# How do you track Caps Lock users with Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I enjoy working with Google Analytics and the ways that I am able to slice information about our visitors.  We use Customer Variables to track information about who and how are users interact with our site.  Staying true to the goal of Analytics, we are always looking for ways to improve and optimize our website.

Currently we are in a phase of development where we can make choices about how we want to store and present product information.  One of the questions that came up was whether or not to show product information in all caps or not.  Working with our users for the last few years, it seems that much of our traffic comes from visitors who do have caps lock on.  So it got us thinking, could we track our caps lock users with a customer variable to that we can make a more informed determination about how to present the information?

Check out this sample I slapped together: http://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/Za4kL/

Our site basically represents a standard e-commerce site.  There are a few different text boxes and that allow you to search for part numbers and throughout the order process there are a few places where users can type text.  Would you bind the caps lock test to all text boxes or just the common ones?  Is there a performance hit if I bind the keypress listener to all text boxes on the site or is it negligible? Is there a better way to implement this?

I imagine instead of showing/hiding a div I would instead set the custom var:

```
_gaq.push('_setCustomVar', 5, 'capslock', 'true', 3);
```

Thanks for any thoughts and consideration on this seemingly trivial topic.

Comment: why do you need to know weather they have caps lock pressed? just use a strtolower function before you search in your db.

Comment: @ted, its not a matter of how we treat the data they search with.  In the spirit of analytics, we're just trying to capture how many users visit our site with caps lock on versus those that do not have it on.

Comment: +1 for the awesomeness of adding a var for capslockusers.

Comment: It's a stretch for me at least to imagine that converting text to SHOUT CAPS would increase anybody's happiness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd bind the event globally, and use the following code:

```
var CAPS_ON = null;
$(window).keypress(function(ev) {
    var charCode = ev.which; //jQuery normalizes ev.charCode to ev.which
    // Lowercase chars
    if (charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122) {
        CAPS_ON = ev.shiftKey; // Caps are off if SHIFT is not pressed
    } else if (charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90) {
        CAPS_ON = !ev.shiftKey;
    }
});
```

This creates a variable `CAPS_ON`, which can be used throughout the page.

Further explanation on the code:

- The event has to be bound to the `keypress` event, because it's the only key event which discerns lowercase/uppercase characters.
- The `shiftKey` property has to be checked, because it inverts the CAPS LOCK feature.

Comment: Of course this requires the user to press a key. But there's no getting around that. You might want to bind this with `$(window).one('keypress', …)` to avoid the overhead for every keypress.

Comment: @MichaelMior That's a good tip if only the initial CAPS lock state has to be known. However, when you're interested in the state on submission of a form, the current method should be used.

Comment: @Michael Mior, this is a great comment but most of our visitors do searches on our site.  Many times their search term begins with a number. The above code looks to only capture a-z and A-Z so if the first letter of the search term is a number we wouldn't have the most accurate information

Comment: @RobW Absolutely. Although if it's a particular form you're interested in, then you probably only want to listen for keypresses in that form.

Comment: @shanabus Also a good point. You might want to consider unbinding the event once `CAPS_ON` has been set after pressing a key in your form. If users are changing caps lock as they are typing, the data probably isn't going to make sense anyway.

Comment: @shanabus This is the cloest you can get using JavaScript. There's no 100% reliable way to check whether text is uppercase through CAPS LOCK: One can copy-paste text, disable JavaScript, mix case, etc.

Comment: This answer is accepted as it was the best way for me to set the variable before calling my tracking code.